# How to migrate Django project to Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I am trying to set up a Django app on Pythonanywhere — I've managed to figure out Bitbucket and clone the code in — I deleted the files in the directory that was provided for me — but can't get it to work.

I've done 'syncdb', then when I go to what I think is the correct URL for the app, I keep getting "Unhandled exception" — The error is that it can't find 'portfolio.settings' in an import (portfolio is the name of the app)

I also have no idea what to put for MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_DIRS — these should be, as far as I know, full paths, not relative.

I'm a Django newbie, and this is proving rather overwhelming, to get the app, which functions fine locally, deployed.  Any help much provided (I haven't found the Pythonanywhere forums — which don't seem indexed -- or help all that helpful, I'm afraid)

I also thought: why don't I let Pythonanywhere set up a blank project for me, but again, I don't know how to handle STATIC_DIRS and MEDIA_ROOT, and I don't really know how to make my project fit their setup.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you have 'porfolio' in INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py?

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- if you let me know your username, and you're happy for me to take a look at your files, I can probably work this one out for you.  If you don't want to post the details here then you can just use the "Send feedback" link on the site.

Comment: @AllTheTime - thanks, yes, I have: # Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'portfolio',
    'south',
)

Comment: @GilesThomas -- thanks very much, I've sent you my user name through your 'send feedback' link on the site.

Comment: Thanks, for the help off-SOF Giles!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else that runs into similar issues:  import errors in web applications are typically to do with your `sys.path` not being correctly configured.  Check your WSGI file (on PythonAnywhere, you can find it on your web tab.  Other hosts may do things differently).

Example:

- `/home/myusername/myproject/` is the project folder
- `/home/myusername/myproject/my_cool_app/` is one of your app folders
- `/home/myusername/myproject/myproject/settings.py` is the settings file location

Your WSGI file should have:

```
sys.path.append('/home/myusername/myproject')
# ...
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'myproject.settings'
```

And your *settings.py* should have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   #...
   'my_cool_app'
```

Everything has to line up so that the dot-notation names of your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` and your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable will import correctly, relative to the folder you add to sys.path.

So in the example above, you could conceivably do:

```
# wsgi file
sys.path.append('/home/myusername')
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'myproject.myproject.settings'
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = 'myproject.my_cool_app'
```

But don't do that, it's overcomplicated.

PS there's a [detailed guide to sys.path and import issues for pythonanywhere](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError) in the docs.

Comment: Assume that to do `sys.path.append('/home/myusername/myproject')` I need first to `import sys`